# ASP.NET / AJAX Download Manager?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, download

I currently have an asp.net page which a loggd in user goes to and theres a bunch of dynamically generated links to zip files that he or she owns and can downloads.

Currently they click download and I have no way of knowing if it completes succesfully etc so can't log it. I do log the attempt.

Is there are good download manager or solution I can use so they will have progress bars on the site, they can queue multiple ones up and **most importantly I can track failed and successful downloads.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with pure asp.net and ajax as the browser sandbox doesn't give you access to the users computer to save the files.

So you need to use some sort of plugin.

[Here's](http://www.aurigma.com/Products/FileDownloader/TechDetails.aspx#tabs) an ActiveX plugin that does what you want but it only works in IE and its expensive. I wouldn't go there...

As you are using Asp.net, a better option would be to write your own download utility in Silverlight.

Bare in mind though, that you'll probably annoy some of your users by forcing them to use your downloader and it will take considerable effort to get a high speed, robust downloader that can compete with the existing browser download managers out there. eg [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/)

Comment: If i went with some sort of java download manager would that be preferred. I think way more users have java than silverlight.

Comment: @nextgenneo - Personally I would go with Silverlight. Silverlight penetration is pretty big and growing, and java seems to have an increasing number of security flaws/exploits. But that's just me. Your situation might be different. However, whatever plugin you use, the issue of forcing a specific downloader on your users will be the same.